# How to find if a column is referenced in a computed column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, dmv, system-tables

I'm trying to mass retype columns. That means first dropping and recreating any constraints they are part of.

I found columns referenced by these constraints

- Foreign Keys,
- Primary Keys,
- Indexes,
- Check constraints,
- Rules,
- Default constraints.

But I cannot find Computed columns.

I've looked into `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE`, but it doesn't include Computed Columns.

There is also `sys.computed_columns` which shows definition, but doesn't list columns in searchable manner.

Is there anywhere else I can look? If SQL Server can figure out the dependence, I thought I would be able to as well.

Comment: Did you look into [sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referenced-entities-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: Yes, that's not it. But you pointed me in the right direction and I found it in sys.sql_expression_dependencies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Scott Hodgin I found it in `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`

```
SELECT 
    OBJECT_NAME(sed.referencing_id)     AS referencingTable
    , pc.[name] AS computedColumn
    , pc.is_computed
    , cc.[name] AS referencedcolumn
    , cc.is_computed
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies sed
JOIN sys.[columns] pc ON sed.referencing_minor_id = pc.column_id AND sed.referencing_id = pc.[object_id]
JOIN sys.[columns] cc ON sed.referenced_minor_id = cc.column_id AND sed.referenced_id = cc.[object_id]
WHERE sed.referencing_minor_id > 0      -- referencing object is Column
AND sed.referenced_minor_id > 0         -- referenced object is Column
AND sed.referencing_id = sed.referenced_id  -- references the same table
```

Answer (score 3):

> There is also sys.computed_columns which shows definition, but doesn't
>   list columns in searchable manner.

If I understand correctly you want to find which columns are referenced by the computed column.

**One solution would be searching the definition in `sys.computed_columns` with `CHARINDEX()` for each column where the `object_id` matches**

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.name, 
                cc.definition 
FROM sys.columns c
CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT definition from sys.computed_columns cc
WHERE c.object_id = cc.object_id
AND CHARINDEX(c.name,cc.definition) > 0
) as cc;
```

---

**Quick test**

```
--Create a heap table.
CREATE TABLE dbo.test(id int,
                      val int);
-- add computed column on two columns.
ALTER TABLE dbo.test 
ADD computedcolumn as id + val;

-- add a column that is not part of any computed column.
ALTER TABLE dbo.test 
ADD bla int;
```

**The query for one specific table**

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.name, 
                cc.definition 
FROM sys.columns c
CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT definition from sys.computed_columns cc
WHERE c.object_id = cc.object_id
AND CHARINDEX(c.name,cc.definition) > 0
) as cc
where c.object_id = object_id('dbo.test');
```

**Result**

```
name    definition
id  ([id]+[val])
val ([id]+[val])
```

Comment: Good answer. Parsing occured to me and this is a good way to go about it. I was looking for a system catalogue, but I see I didn't specify it in the question. If there isn't a better answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Zikato  Thanks! I agree that there should be a better way to get it than parsing, maybe someone else knows a way to get it through a dmv.